# Textbook/resources for a beginning researcher in (Machine) Learning Theory

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

I'm looking to begin understanding basic concepts, notions, results and definitions in the area of Computational Learning Theory (or the theory of Machine Learning), as is done in the **theoretical** computer science community (those represented mainly in STOC/FOCS). My goal is to do research in the area from the strictly theoretical perspective.

What kind of textbooks/resources, basic papers are available for me?
What kind of knowledge I need to have? Algorithms theory, or computational complexity theory? Or probability/probabilistic-methods (a la, Alon-Spencer)?

I have only seen a single textbook *An Introduction to Computational Learning Theory* by Michael Kearns and Umesh Virkumar Vazirani (1994), but I don't know if this is adequate/up to date.

So the question shortly is:
**How can a researcher start obtaining knowledge in theoretical Machine Learning**? (Note I'm not interested as of now in any form of applications of ML.)

Comment: See this thread https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/35965/convergence-and-representation-theorems-for-machine-learning/35967#35967

Answer (score 5):

People are going to recommend

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/

and

http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf

-- so I might as well do it first :)

I still think the Anthony-Bartlett is a better start for the mathematically oriented beginner.

Comment: Are these books adequate to those interested solely in STOC/FOCS style theoretical machine learning (if this style even exists)? As I'm not searching to understand applications (note the second book claims to speak about ML applications).

Comment: For *that* you probably still can't beat Kearns-Vazirani.

Comment: I see; this was my original question. So you do think that Kearns-Vazirani is the most suitable for strict theory of ML?

Comment: Also, check out O'Donnell's book -- it has many learning applications http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Classes/2016-PRG/Analysis-Of-Boolean-Functions.pdf

Comment: PS you should really check out those books in my answer if you want to enter the area of ML as a researcher -- theory or applied.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't follow precisely. Above you said that for theoretical ML as represented in STOC/FOCS Kearns-Vazinary is the best as a start, right? So do you think that also the other two books are essential? Note that one cannot start with more than one book.

Comment: Your OP indicates that you'd like to eventually publish in ICML,NIPS,COLT, etc. For that, you'll definitely need the more up-to-date material of the other books I linked.

Comment: I see. So perhaps I was not explaining the question correctly. I'm not interested in ICML, NIPS or COLT per se. I'm interested in what is happening in "STOC/FOCS" style ML. And any paper that is in the *intersection* of STOC/FOCS and ICML,NIPS, COLT (but not outside this intersection) :)

Comment: Advances in ML roughly decompose into algorithmic and statistical types. For the latter, you'll definitely need those books I linked. For the former, I am not aware of a modern algorithmic learning textbook beyond K-V. Perhaps someone should write one.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know this. This is one of the reasons I asked the question. Perhaps you can elaborate on this in your answer above? What does this separation mean?

Comment: See here for elaboration https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/35965/convergence-and-representation-theorems-for-machine-learning/35967#35967

Comment: But this still means that K-V is NOT enough even for the purely STOC/FOCS ML, because FOCS/STOC ML do contain statistical ML theory papers, right? Hence the answer should have been: K-V + parts of the other texts, correct?

Comment: If you resolve the status of noisy parity or learning DNF, you'll have no trouble getting that paper into STOC/FOCS.

Comment: Yes; but this is not precisely the question. The question is not what is the minimal set of books/resources enough to understand/write *some* papers in "FOCS/STOC" style ML. Rather, it aims to learn *every* FOCS/STOC style ML.

Comment: It's still an ill-posed question. No single book is ever *enough*. You start somewhere (and KV is a great place to start) and then play catch-up.

Comment: And by your patient answers I understand that K-V is a good start, but to follow also statistical ML in STOC/FOCS I would need also some parts of the other books, correct?

Comment: Absolutely! If you want a condensed intro course on the statistical issues, check out the one I taught -- the material is mostly online: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~asml162/Class_Material

Comment: I don't think it is ill-posed, because of the following simple example: it is obvious that there are some books that are completely irrelevant for me (e.g., books on hardware architecture). So the question is what is the minimum number of topics/books/resources that cover contemporary STOC/FOCS style ML.

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be one. It's a very rapidly expanding field.

Comment: yes, no one book. But a collection of books; with K-V as a good start. I begin to understand with your help. Thanks!

Comment: ... or even one (small) set of books...